# Passing va_list from rust variadic to C

Tags: rust, ffi

is it possible to pass variadic arguments from rust to C function?

```rust
extern "C" fn foo(fmt: const *i8, args: ...) {
    let buf1024 = vec![0; 1024];
    // How to pass args to wvsprintfA?
    winapi::um::winuser::wvsprintfA(
        buf1024.as_mut_ptr(),
        fmt,
        ?
    );
}
```

Comment: The interface for va_list is experimental. But why won't you use `wsprintfA()`?

Comment: can you provide an example with `wsprintfA`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman

Comment: If you need to accept `...` then you cannot use it. The problem is that `winapi` doesn't use the same definition as the experimental varargs support. Is your function needed to be called from Rust or C? Perhaps you can take `va_list` directly?

Comment: The `foo` function is being called from C code. As I don't want to implement wprintf by myself I just wanted to call a winapi `wsprintfW` or `wvsprintfW` function. The syntax of winapi does not bother me, as I can use `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcInfo` and provide my own type - just not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: The problem is that you need to call the function with the definition provided by `winapi`. Can you take `va_list` instead of `...`?

Comment: Will have to confirm, but I think that yes

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I have confirmed that I can invoke wsprintfW and wvsprintfW and pass any type of argument I want just by using std::mem::transmute. However still unable to pass the va_list properly.


`let func= GetProcAddr(dll_handle, "wsprintfW"); // or wvsprintfW
let f: extern "C" fn(buf: *mut u16, fmt: *const u16, ...) -> u32 = std::mem::transmute(func);
func(out_buf.as_mut_ptr(), fmt.as_ptr(), args.as_va_list());`

Comment: What I meant is that you take winapi's `va_list` in your function. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=299f2ba1ab6ebfe5b42050c37b3fbd8d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Chayim Friedman answer in comments, I ended using GetProcAddr with mem::transmute:

```rust
let dll_handle = LoadLibrary("user32.dll");
let func_addr = GetProcAddr(dll_handle, "wvsprintfW");
let f: extern "C" fn(buf: *mut u16, fmt: *const u16, args: std::ffi::VaList) -> u32 = std::mem::transmute(func_addr);
f(out_buf.as_mut_ptr(), fmt.as_ptr(), args.as_va_list());
```